# How to redirect stdout and stderr from csh script

Tags: redirect, csh

For the following script

**install.csh:**

```
#!/bin/csh -f
tar -zxf Python-3.1.1.tgz
cd Python-3.1.1
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-3.1.1
```

Intended use:

```
./install.csh |& tee install.log
```

How can I change the script so that I still get a install.log and the output on console without asking the user to do the redirecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some simple solutions:

Solution 1:
tee every line you want to log independently, make use of `-a` switch of tee to append

```
#!/bin/csh -f    
tar -zxf Python-3.1.1.tgz |& tee -a install.log
cd Python-3.1.1 |& tee -a install.log
./configure |& tee -a install.log
make |& tee -a install.log
make install |& tee -a install.log
cd .. |& tee -a install.log
rm -rf Python-3.1.1 |& tee -a install.log
```

Solution 2: Add a second script.
For example, rename current install.csh to install_commands,
then add a new install.csh script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f 
/bin/csh install_commands |& tee install.log
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking there might be some other trick which I don't know of leading to an elegant solution.

Comment: Oooh. good call to split it into two scripts. +1 Still don't think you should be sticking with csh though! (-:

Answer (score 3):

G'day,

I **highly** recommend moving away from csh towards something like bash or zsh.

stdio manipulation is not possible in csh. Have a read of "[csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)". An elegant treatise on this topic.

Sorry it's not a direct answer but you'll find that you'll keep banging your head against the constraints of csh the longer you stick with it.

A lot of csh syntax is already available in bash so your learning curve won't be too steep.

Here's a quick suggestion for the same thing written in bash. It's not elegant though.

```
#!/bin/bash
TO_LOGFILE= "| tee -a ./install.log"
tar -zxf Python-3.1.1.tgz 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Untar of Python failed. Exiting..."; exit 5
fi

cd Python-3.1.1 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Can't change into Python dir. Exiting..."; exit 5
fi
echo "============== configure ================"
./configure 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Configure failed. Exiting..."; exit 5
fi
echo "================ make ==================="
make 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Compile of Python failed. Exiting..."; exit 5
fi
echo "================ install ================"
make install 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo "Install of Python failed. Exiting..."; exit 5
fi

cd ..
rm -rf Python-3.1.1 2>&1 ${TO_LOGFILE}
exit 0
```

I've added a bit more checking and reporting so that if there's a problem in an earlier step the log file will just contain up until the error was uncovered rather than a stack of pretty useless error messages from the later phases that wouldn't complete anyway.

cheers,

Comment: @Shelly, oops. forgot you wanted to duplicate to console.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in a subshell and redirect all the output of that. Don't remember if this works in csh, it has been a long, long time since I used that.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
(
tar -zxf Python-3.1.1.tgz
cd Python-3.1.1
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-3.1.1
) |& tee install.log
```