# How to redirect php exec stderr into output array when shell is csh?

Tags: php, freebsd, csh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect stdout and stderr from csh script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849358/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-from-csh-script)

I've done this many times before when the server's execution shell is sh or bash:

```
exec('dostuff 2>&1', $output, $return);
```

But now my server is on FreeBSD and the Apache execution shell is csh. I have been doing this:

```
exec('dostuff |& cat', $output, $return);
```

I am not sure this is correct, or optimal. Anybody have a better way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you are not sure about something and you ask yourself how it is programmed or if there is a unspecified better way does not qualify as a programming question per-se. I added a related question as possible duplicate, however in my eyes your question could be closed right away as "not constructive".

Answer (score 0):

Use [`proc_open`()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to get output from stderr.

Comment: Seems far too complex for my simple cases. Is there no way to redirect stderr onto stdout in csh?

Comment: @user9645: If you would have researched your issue, you would have known hours ago. See the linked duplicate in comments below your question.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.